# Are there any good brute force programs in C#?

Tags: brute-force, software

I'm planning to research & learn from brute force methods, but all the popular ones I found like John the Ripper or hashcat are written in C & OpenGL which I don't have much knowledge about so far. Can anybody recommend a decent brute force program written in C#, if it includes source code that would be nice.

Comment: Interesting question. C# would probably be a poor choice for a brute force application because of garbage collection, and to use GPU you’d probably need to marshal across to unmanaged libraries. That would be quite slow. C is the language of choice for this type of application because speed is critical for effectiveness.

Comment: yeah i learn about that recently but i barely knew C or OpenCL for the moment. Is there any specific document instruct you how to write a brute force program in C?

Comment: In it’s simplest form, a brute force attack would just be a while loop, testing variations on input. Beyond that, it gets much more complex depending on the system you are attacking. I don’t have a recommendation, but you might want to just learn to use the tools and why they work before trying to reverse engineer them.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to learn about brute force methods?

Comment: @user52472 there're two key method i like to learn; generate, hash password & check them with hash list, both as fast as possible. I did write some small project but never check the hash result in one second when lots of program can do so

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any particular brute force in C#, but having worked in both C and C# (and inferring that you know C# from your question) I think with a good reference you should be able to jump into C. You will of course need to be very careful with garbage collection (malloc, etc.) and it will require learning procedural vs. object oriented coding but it's doable.

Here's a good thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002442/learning-c-from-a-background-in-c-sharp

One of the recommendations is [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131103628) which is a classic. For something much lighter and very funny I'm a fan of Dan Gookin's [C for Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003S9VR16) which is light but still informative.

Good luck!

Comment: You are asking him to learn C language. OP asked for recommending a brute force program. Normally this forum is not suitable/allow for recommendation and your answer is very generic. You should have mentioned fuzzy testing/buffer overflow, etc.

Comment: That's true, but in the follow up comments, and perhaps I should put information in there, OP talked about writing a program in C which is why my answer contained the information it did. Thank you very much though for the feedback and I'll keep trying to improve my answers! Cheers!